# Angular addEventListener with options

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener

How to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function with options with Angular 5? If there is document, could you please point me to it? Thanks

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
```

Angular way of listening to event method don't seem to allow that.

inside HTML template

```
<div (click)='handleClick()'/>
```

[Angular renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) listen method:

```
listen(target: 'window' | 'document' | 'body' | any, eventName: string, callback: (event: any) => boolean | void): () => void
```

[HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)

```
@HostListener({ 
  eventName?: string
  args?: string[]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

For example with document which listen scroll:

```
@HostListener('document:scroll', null) listenScroll(agrs?): void {
   //logic here
}
```

listenScroll() is a method with args which you can use in template.

`'document:scroll'` is a specific target like "listen scroll in document, if changed, do logic"

UPDATE: for `addEventListener`

You need target element to attach event, so:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private _elemRef: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this._elemRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('document', (event) => {
         //do logic
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but an example is not what I am looking for. There are example(s) at Angular repo.

Comment: So why you want to use `addEventListener`? Angular highly recommend using `@HostListener` for this ;)